# Announcing a Pro Tempore election

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Korean Language Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://korean.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **September 24** to bring in one more moderator.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Between now and September 24, users can decide whether to nominate themselves and ask questions of candidates on meta. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- During the nomination period, users may [nominate themselves on the election page](https://korean.stackexchange.com/election/1) and answer any questions that might have been [asked on meta](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election?sort=newest).
- On October 1, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on October 9.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

> During the nomination period, users may nominate themselves...

How exactly should a willing user nominate themselves? In a reply to this meta question?

> ...and ask questions of candidates on meta.

Again, is there a suggested format for this? (Do you anticipate a new meta question per 'question to the candidates'?). I don't anticipate a huge number of these but you never know!

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there usually a separate thread for nominations once the nominations start?

Comment: @user17915 yes - I think I was a bit confused by "Between now and September 24, users can decide whether to nominate themselves and ask questions of candidates on meta", 'cos there aren't any candidates yet - but I guess the point is to ask meta questions that candidates *can* answer once we know who they are..?

Comment: Once the election starts, people will be able to nominate themselves [on the election page](https://korean.stackexchange.com/election/1). I'm gonna clear up the language a bit in my announcement template.

Comment: @JonEricson thanks. If this is a template, I still think "users can decide whether to nominate themselves and ask questions of candidates on meta" is a bit confusing - because before the nomination period, we don't know who the candidates are. Perhaps "users can consider whether they will want to nominate themselves, and ask questions for candidates to answer on meta" ?

Comment: Ah. I see that now. I'll rephrase for next time. Thanks!

Comment: @JonEricson Probably just my inability to unmisunderstand :)