# 2018 Moderator Election - We need more candidates!

Tags: discussion, election

The [nomination phase of the moderator elections](https://korean.stackexchange.com/election/1) was scheduled to end today. However, we didn't get any candidates. Remember, this is a [*pro tempore* election](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/announcing-a-pro-tempore-election). Having users actively curating the site is [critical for its continued existence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites). In order to find more willing volunteers, we will be extending the deadline for nominations for an additional seven days.

We need leadership to come from within this community, the election can't move forward unless someone wants to take on the responsibility. Did you consider nominating but decided not to for some reason? Now would be a great time to reconsider!

Comment: There's now one candidate, but they're already an existing moderator who's standing for reconfirmation. Is this allowed? Second, if there are still no candidates by the time this extension ends, what will happen?

Comment: @gparyani: It's a bit odd, but we allow moderators to run because they have to in the first election after graduation. If the existing moderator is the only candidate, I'll talk with the moderator team and see if we really need to add a moderator. As long as we have three moderators who are keeping the site clear of spam and such, there's no further action. The bigger problem is if we end up with nobody interested in curating the site.

Comment: My guess is that this moderator is intending to resign should another user nominate themselves and get elected instead. Please contact the moderator in question and ask them if that's their intent.

Comment: @gparyani (sorry, I misread your previous comment.) As I understand it, the election is only for one position, so if another user does nominate themselves and get elected, they will replace the outgoing moderator.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I'm actually not very active here, and only just saw through the "Please cast your vote ..." notification that there's only one moderator up for election (and that they were looking to retire). I'm sure everyone would prefer someone who's actually active, **so read no further if any less is undesirable!**

---

I've been interested in this proposal for some time—since its commitment phase I believe. I never really became a daily (or even weekly) user, but as someone primarily motivated by helping people, moderatorship would probably ramp up my involvement. So, still deferring to active members first, please let me know if I can get involved.

I imagine my first steps would be something like,

- sync with current mods about the happenings, issues that come up more often than others (if any), and what they have in mind to grow this site,
- go through old questions (I notice not too many are unanswered, though—nice!) and get a feel for the makeup and level of visitors and experts,
- and start doing some cleanup / work on flags.

My previous SE experience includes pro-tem moderating [beer.se](https://beer.stackexchange.com) in its first few years and founding [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). I promise not to bot-ify any duties here.

My experience with Korean is a little weird. I can explain if asked, but for now, I don't think it's relevant to fulfilling moderator duties.

Comment: Hi Andrew! I'm going to be cancelling this election for now. The mod is planning on staying on. But I expect we'll have another election in the future and I hope you'll be ready then!

Comment: Oh okay! I didn't catch that discussion. No worries, glad it was worked out, thanks.

Comment: Hi Andrew - at the risk of stating the obvious, just to say that any extra help in the areas you mention would be very welcome... from https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/privileges you will see that you don't need that much rep here to do many 'moddy' things, even without being a 'diamond' mod.

Comment: @topomorto - Of course! It seems I misinterpreted the situation. Seeing only one nominee in the list, I didn't realize at the time there were also 2 other moderators staying onboard. And having been part of betas I liked that failed, as well as moderating a beta that was in danger of failing due to low stats, I jumped the gun, not wanting this beta to die if the only reason was the lack of a moderator. (I edited my question later when I realized there were actually other mods sticking around.) Glad you're staying on board!